# What ensure Netty handlers will get GCed

Tags: http, netty

I have written http server and have couple of custom handlers too. Sometimes I want to explicitly close the client connection if some error occurs etc. So in that case what I do is channelHandlerContext.close(). Will this enough to let this handler object GCed. Do I have to do override channelInactive() and do something more ?

Answer (score 2):

This will be enough as the pipeline will be cleared on close